# How do I connect each circle to the top left corner in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

So far I have this code, and am needing to draw a line from the top left corner when each circle is clicked. However, I only have a star constellation type right now, where is circle connects to the next circle instead.

```py
from pygame import * 

init()
size = width, height = 650, 650
screen = display.set_mode(size)

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)

running = True
myClock = time.Clock()
prev_pos = None

# Game Loop
while running:
    for e in event.get(): 
        if e.type == QUIT:
            running = False
        if e.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if e.button == 1:
                if prev_pos != None:
                    draw.line(screen, GREEN, prev_pos, e.pos)
                prev_pos = e.pos
                draw.circle(screen, GREEN, e.pos, 10)
            if e.button == 3:     
                prev_pos = None 
                screen.fill(BLACK)

    display.flip()
    myClock.tick(60)

quit()
```

Answer (score 2):

The top left of the screen is `(0,0)`.  The line drawing function documentation can be found here: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.line

So simply changing your line-drawing code:

```
TOP_LEFT = ( 0, 0 )

...

draw.line( screen, GREEN, TOP_LEFT, e.pos )
```

Will give you a line from the upper-left corner to the centre of each circle.

All these operations are pretty simple, it will really help you learn if you take the short time to read through the documentation - at least for the operation you're trying to achieve.  Copy and pasting code from SO is not really a good way to learn anything.